# Json parsing error with react - value not found

Tags: reactjs

I am a getting a weird error with react when trying to parse and 1 level below in the json tree.

you can get the full api response with: https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=tree&api-key=cx9iwv3jo9jwjuLglDR6fXA4x8de1qlZ

images are available under multimedia (array) and under the value of key 'url'

[image]

I am getting an error with the syntax media[0].url

we can read the output of media[0].url. it works, the value is not null, but react throws an error. what to do here?

Comment: You are seeing the output of the *previous* iteration, not the one that throws the error (because it's the console.log line that throws it.) Try `console.log(media[0])` instead.

Comment: printing  console.log(media[0]) gives me a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's drill down into this error. It says: `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` at line `console.log(media[0].url)`.

This means that `media[0]` is `undefined`.

*Why would `media[0]` be undefined*?

One possibility is that `media` is an empty array (length 0) or not an array at all.

Either way, this is not a React issue, it's a Javascript issue. Note that in JavaScript, unlike other languages it is perfectly legal to access non-existent properties. It just returns undefined instead of throwing a type error. Similarly, arrays indices are treated as properties. So an out of bounds access returns undefined.

However, attempting to access an `undefined` or `null` throws an error.

```
const x = {'data': [1, 2, 3]};
console.log(x.value) // undefined

const arr = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr[4]) // undefined

// attempt array access on a non-array
console.log(x[0]) // undefined

// access undefined
console.log(undefined[0]) // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

The best thing to do is to print your values at each step to make sure everything is as expected. Alternatively, you can use **Typescript**, a programming language similar to JavaScript which checks for these types of errors at compile time and can therefore prevent nasty bugs.

Comment: nothing is undefined. the previous step with  console.log(media[0]) gives me a value

Comment: What value is this? I think you are looking at the value from the previous iteration of the `map` in which no error was raised.

Comment: @sandraoo Undefined is not a value. It means that `media[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: @fizzybear thanks. 1 iteration is missing the multimedia, hence the undefined for 1 value. I missed that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response from the endpoint, some of the entries in `docs` have an empty array for `multimedia`.

When you reference an element of an array that does exist you get undefined.

```js
console.log([][0])
```

and trying to reference a property from `undefined` will throw an error (as you have)